# Select and copy a cell to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

If conditions in two columns are met this code is supposed to take a value from another sheet and paste it into the end of the row of the checked row to the source sheet.

For testing purpose, I tried to keep it at a specific range.

`cell.Value` is most likely wrong and the range is probably not working as I imagined. Also, it is probably not looping through the columns.

I have different cell possibilities to copy for different conditions and I suppose I can adjust them each depending on the conditions.

```vb
Sub Update()
Dim Column As Range
Sheets("Q485").Select
Set Column = Range.Select("AV:AW")
    If Column("AW") Is cell.Value("P") And Column("AV") Is cell.Value("V") Then
        Sheets("Support").Select
        Range("C9").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Q485").Select
        Range("AY6358").Select
        Selection.Paste
'    Else 
'    Other conditions will be written below
    end if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub MyMacroc ()
    Dim rng as range
    set rng = sheets("Source").range("A2:A7")

    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        with cel
            'condition -1 '
            if .offset(0,1)="P" and .Offset(0,2)="V" then
                .offset(0,3) = Sheets("Extract").range("B2")
            ElseIF
                'your second conition 
            end if
        end with
    next

End sub
```